# The send_bulkledger function is called multiple times instead of just once

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

```
if main1['res']['message']['module'] == 'bulk_ledger_save':
    ledger_list = await self.save_bulk_ledger(main1) # returns a list
    print('6000')
    msgdict = {"msg":"bulk_legder_return", "ledger_list": ledger_list}
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(self.room_group_name,
                                        {"type":"send_bulkledger", 'msg':msgdict})

async def send_bulkledger(self, event):
    print(event, '7000')
    data = event['msg']
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"msg":data}))
```

This code belongs to Django Channels.

While running above code "6000" is printing only once
but "7000" is printing multiple times.

why is "7000" called several times?

Comment: You don't give enough information. where is this code called from? what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Hey dude, please add file name maybe? And maybe some more background info or something what you tried or any hints for it. Maybe add a link to programming tutorial related to this if possible as well?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.